# Mobile - how to reconcile view title and action button title?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, buttons, user-expectation

I have a view in a mobile app responsible for stitching photos into a video. I’m looking for advise on how to make the title of this screen match the text of a single action button on the same screen. The objective is to make it clear to the user that they are creating or making a video.

**How do I pick view title and action button title for a screen requiring user to press the action button?**

- are there guidelines to follow on screen-button naming?
- should the action button and title be the same?
- should th action button be a shorter version of the title?
- how many words should an action button title have?
- should action button have redundant or obvious words?

[image]

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the interaction. Is the user previewing the video on this screen as well as being able to actually create/save the video? Or are they coming to this screen just to create/save it, having already seen a preview on a different screen?

Answer (score 2):

Are they making a video or sharing a video? Is sharing the video part of the larger video creation flow, or is the only action on this screen sharing?

Based on my reading of your question, it sounds like sharing is part of the larger, multi-step video creation flow. If so, the title should be about creating the video. Sharing that video once it's been recorded may be the primary action on this particular step—there's nothing wrong with that.

The problem would be if each step in the process had its own screen with its own title. In that case, you'd want to make sure the action and the title are complimentary. Something like 'Share Video' as the title and 'Share Now' as the CTA.